# Controller's length property does not match the number of tabs present in TabBar's tabs property

Tags: flutter, tabs, init, tabview

I am implementing an TabBar but getting the error, as state above. I know the reason this is happening, but can't figure how to fix this.

I have an async function designed to pull data from Firebase which populates a list. The function is described below. The data pulled by this function is used to pass the length to the TabController.

Function to call data from Firebase:

```
Future functionName async {

await function actions...
  List example = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
}
```

This function is used in a **Future Builder**, which returns a widget to display, as soon as the function execution is complete.

The future of the Future Builder is initialised in the initState() of the class. The init() state looks like:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _future = functionName();

    tabController = TabController(length: example.length, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);

    tabController.addListener(_setActiveTabIndex);
 }
```

Now, I get the error, as stated above. Which is obvious, why! 
As the function is an async function and is built in a Future Builder, initially the list 'example' is empty. And the TabController gets a length of 0. But as this list gets populated, the length increases, but the length of the TabController does not change.

I have tried using :

```
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

    _future = functionName();

    setState(() {
       tabController = TabController(length : example. length, vsync : this, initialIndex : 0)
  } 
)
```

But this doesn't work either.
It's annoying to know the issue, but not being able to fix it. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the reason of the problem.

The hole idea it's kind of backwards.

You are trying to build the `TabBar`, before you know how many tabs you need.

---

You can

- Execute your `FutureBuilder` and then build the `TabBar` with the data received.

Or you can

- Get the data before you go to that screen, so have the data already.

---

I hope this put you on the right track

Comment: Okay, I just tried the second method and it works. I never thought of that ... It's brilliant. So, I'll mark this answer as correct and solved. I really appreciate it. :)
Having said that, I am using a future builder, and after the function call gets successfully completed, I use the call that builds and returns the TabBar. But I have to nominate the TabController in the initState(). How do you suggest I can get around that problem, if I wanted to? Is there a way to do that?